# KMM cocoapods cannot import XCFramework

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

```
cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "12.0"
        podfile = project.file("../ios/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = false
            transitiveExport = true
            embedBitcode(BitcodeEmbeddingMode.DISABLE)
        }
//        pod("TXIMSDK_Plus_iOS"){moduleName = "ImSDK_Plus"} //is worked!!!

        // xcframework Failed to generate cinterop for :shared:cinteropImSDK_PlusIosSimulatorArm64:
        // fatal error: module 'ImSDK_Plus' not found        
       pod("TXIMSDK_Plus_iOS_XCFramework") {
            version = libs.versions.tencent.imsdk.get()
            packageName = "ImSDK_Plus"
            moduleName = "ImSDK_Plus" 
            val xcFrameworkPathDir = project.layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile.resolve("shared/cocoapods/synthetic/ios/Pods/TXIMSDK_Plus_iOS_XCFramework/ImSDK_Plus.xcframework")

            extraOpts = listOf(
                "-compiler-option", "-DNS_FORMAT_ARGUMENT(A)=",
                "-verbose"
            )
        }
        extraSpecAttributes["resources"] =
            "['src/commonMain/resources/**', 'src/iosMain/resources/**']"
    }
```

I have spent the whole day searching on Google or Chatgpt, and all I found were discussions about exporting XCframeworks, but none about importing remote dependencies of XCframeworks.

Comment: libs.versions.tencent.imsdk.get() == "7.6.5021",

my flutter with kmm project https://github.com/vickyleu/flutter_with_kmm.git

Comment: have you been able to progress somehow? Just find your post and i am facing similiar issue